# Using composition or inheritance to enhance this linked list

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, linked-list

**Problem Statement:**

> A method called insertEnd() exists, but it runs in linear time, because every time it is called, it walks down the list to find the end.  Without changing the meaning of this method or any other, modify the representation of a SList and whatever methods are necessary to make insertEnd() run in constant time. Your SList class will need to continually maintain a record of the last (tail) SListNode in an SList, and all SList's methods will have to ensure that this record stays current.

`SList` class & `SListNode` class are already provided in the assignment as shown below:

**SListNode**

```
/* SListNode.java */
class SListNode {
  Object item;
  SListNode next;


  /**
   *  SListNode() (with two parameters) constructs a list node referencing the
   *  item "obj", whose next list node is to be "next".
   */

  SListNode(Object obj, SListNode node) {
    item = obj;
    this.next = node;
  }

  /**
   *  SListNode() (with one parameter) constructs a list node referencing the
   *  item "obj".
   */

  SListNode(Object obj) {
    this(obj, null);
  }
}
```

---

**SList**

```
/* SList.java */

  public class SList {

  protected SListNode head;
  protected int size;

  /**
   *  SList() constructs an empty list.
   **/

  public SList() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
  }

  /**
   *  insertFront() inserts item "obj" at the beginning of this list.
   *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
   **/

  public void insertFront(Object obj) {
    head = new SListNode(obj, head);
    size++;
  }

  /**
   *  insertEnd() inserts item "obj" at the end of this list.
   *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
   **/

  public void insertEnd(Object obj) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = new SListNode(obj);
    } else {
      SListNode node = head;
      while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
      }
      node.next = new SListNode(obj);
    }
    size++;
  }
}
```

---

Below is the solution for the given problem:

**TailList**

```
/* TailList.java */

public class TailList extends SList{
    private SListNode tail;

    public TailList(){
        tail = null;
    }

    /**
     *  insertEnd() inserts item "obj" at the end of this list.
     *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
     **/

    public void insertEnd(Object obj) {
        if(this.size > 0){
            SListNode node  = new SListNode(obj);
            this.tail.next = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }else{
            this.head = this.tail = new SListNode(obj);
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    /**
     *  insertFront() inserts item "obj" at the beginning of this list.
     *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
     **/

    public void insertFront(Object obj){
        super.insertFront(obj);
        if(size == 1){
            tail = head;
        }
    }
}
```

My question:

Does `TailList` class inheritance relation with `SList` implementation class looks fine(within same package)? How do I know whether `SList` class is specifically designed for inheritance, as mentioned below?

> It is safe to use inheritance within a package, where the subclass and the superclass implementations are under the control of the same programmers. It is also safe to use inheritance when **extending classes specifically designed** and documented for extension
>   (Item 17). Inheriting from ordinary concrete classes across package boundaries,
>   however, is dangerous. As a reminder, this book uses the word “inheritance” to mean implementation inheritance (when one class extends another). The problems discussed in this item do not apply to interface inheritance (when a class implements an interface or where one interface extends another).

Comment: As I interpret the problem statement, you're free to just edit the code of `SList` directly.

Comment: @200_success As per the [assignment](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/lab/lab3/), `head` & `size` are private. I guess, same package mean a single programmer would have control over existing classes. Thank you for rephrasing my question title.

Comment: Shall i make  `private SListNode tail;` as `protected SListNode tail;`?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that…

1. You have full access to the source code of the original `SList` class
2. To make inheritance work, you had to edit `SList.java` to change `head` and `size` from private to protected access
3. The assignment asks you to "modify the representation of `SList`"
4. The resulting class performs the same task as the original code, adding no new functionality (just a large performance optimization for `insertEnd()` with a negligible cost to `insertFront()`)

I see no reason to use either inheritance or composition.  Just edit `SList.java` directly to modify its implementation.  The resulting `SList` class should be fully substitutable with the original, just with better performance characteristics.

Comment: Ok. With current problem statement, To enhance the `insertEnd()` performance, we came up with new subclass `TailList`. But there would be new problems given in future to embed in same class `TailList` which can't be forecasted right now. So, considering that, Would i not think about how `TailList` would be presented? Another point is, When we introduce subclass, the invariants that parent class  enforces should also be enforced by sub class.

Comment: For all practical purposes, having a `TailList` class can do no good. All it does is introduce a slightly incompatible data representation — if you happen to have existing `SList`s in a program, you can't cast it to `TailList`. I don't see where the exercise asks you to use inheritance, and if it did, it would be a silly exercise of little educational value.

Comment: yes, you are right, we do not require new subclass, if we add `tail` as member to `SList`, it does not add any performance degradation in `Slist` class.

Comment: ya, inheritance concept is being introduced  with this wrong example, which is surprising. [lecturelink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZo3HSssgIk)

Comment: one important question, if `SList` is owned by different team(different package)  within the same organization where they used `protected` fields for `head` & `size`. How would i approach to resolve this performance problem of `insertEnd()` to use `SList` in my package?

Comment: A practical answer: Choose data structures that are appropriate for the job. Usually, that means don't use linked lists at all. If you must use a linked list, `java.util.LinkedList` is probably the one to use. Don't reinvent the wheel, and you won't have silly problems like that.

Comment: In general, my question is, If `Xyz` is a class than is owned by different team(different package) within the same organization. How do i approach to enhance some method `abc()` to gain performance? Do i need to ask them to enhance it? or It is our call to go with our own changes?